# Test whether sluggish Win 10 laptop is due to SSD speed reduction due to getting full

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, performance

I have a Dell Win 10 Laptop with an SSD and I have noticed its responsiveness has slowed down over the past few months. Things like opening files, saving files etc. are slower than they used to be on this same laptop.

Now what I do not know is whether this is related to some OS / program issue or just the SSD slowing down as it gets full. Is there a good way to test whether this is an SSD speed issue? In that case I can fix it by deleting files and making the SSD less full.

If it helps the SSD is 450 GB and currently shows 130 GB empty and 320 GB full. That would be 70% full. The hardware spec shows ***"SK Hynix BC 511 NVMe 512 GB"***

Comment: 70% should not be a problem for an SSD, assuming TRIM support is active in Windows for that SSD. You can check if there is a firmware update for the SSD (but make full backup first before installing an update).

Comment: Thanks! @Robert I checked under "Optimize Drives" on Win10 and it shows last retrimmed 1 day ago and on a weekly cycle.